# Can it be harmful to grant jackd realtime priority?

Tags: apt, jack, realtime, process-priority, ardour

I am apt-get installing Ardour, a sound mixing program, just to try it out. Installing Ardour also installs JACK, a dependency. As part of the JACK installation script, I get the following dialog:

> If you want to run jackd with realtime priorities, the user starting jackd needs realtime permissions. Accept this option to create the file /etc/security/limits.d/audio.conf, granting realtime priority and memlock privileges to the audio group.
>
> Running jackd with realtime priority minimizes latency, but may lead to complete system lock-ups by requesting all the available physical system memory, which is unacceptable in multi-user environments.
>
> Enable realtime process priority?

I'm installing on my laptop, which never has multiple simultaneous users. I still have concerns: is JACK something that'll be used by the system itself to play any sound (i.e. will it replace ALSA)? If so, does that mean that if I enable realtime priority for JACK, I'll run a slight risk of freezing the machine whenever any sound is played? Or is JACK only going to be used by Ardour for now (until I install some other JACK-dependent program)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Jackd does not normally replace ALSA.  Jackd usually uses ALSA to provide it's output.  What Jackd provides is a low-latency audio patching/routing network that other software can use.  Only software designed to use Jackd will use JackD.  Jackd only needs to be run when you are running software that uses it (*e.g.* Ardour, Rosegarden, Jack-rack).  When you are not running a program that uses jackd, you don't have to run jackd.

The best program I have found for controlling jackd is qjackctl, which can be installed through the Ubuntu Software Center as Jack Control.  It allows starting/stopping jackd, configuring how it is run, and setting up connections.

In order to get the lowest latency possible, jackd really would like to use real-time priority threads.  Enabling real-time processing for jackd is good thing to do and should not hurt your system.  (The machine I am typing on right now has had it enabled for 4 years under 2 different Linux distros and 2 different hardware incarnations without any lock-ups.)

BTW, once you start using some of the features of jackd, it gets pretty addictive.  By starting up different effects racks (jack-rack instances), and setting up the connections, I can take take a stereo recording and create a real-time 4.2 output where I have different delays reverb/delay for the rear speakers, a custom center channel mix, and a sub-woofer output.  (I am still trying to find a good octave doubler for that.)

Answer (score 2):

One approach to the realtime lockup problem is simply open a `bash` terminal with a higher priority than `jackd`. Use your high priority terminal to kill `jackd` if you see signs of realtime CPU hogging. I used this to avoid total crashes before learning the art of irq fine tuning for pro audio. Steep learning curve, great rewards!

Comment: Would be helpful to describe how to open a bash terminal with a higher priority than jackd.

Comment: Yeah, especially if `jackd` is running **realtime**